# jQuery take href value and insert into dropdown menu

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that is automatically generated, I want jQuery code help me to take out the value of every `href` (the part: "/listing-agent-staff/barack-obama"), and insert this value into a drop down menu.

**the auto generated code:**

```
<div class="StaffBlock StaffName">
<a href="/listing-agent-staff/barack-obama">Barack Obama</a>
</div>
<div class="StaffBlock StaffName">
<a href="/listing-agent-staff/bill-clinton">Bill Clinton</a>
</div>
<div class="StaffBlock StaffName">
<a href="/listing-agent-staff/will-smith">Will Smith</a>
</div>
```

**the dropdown menu I want the value to be inserted to:**

```
<label for="CAT_Custom_231994">Listing Contact</label>
<select name="CAT_Custom_231994" id="CAT_Custom_231994" class="cat_dropdown">
<option value="">-- Please select --</option>
<option value="/listing-agent-staff/barack-obama">Barack Obama</option>
<option value="/listing-agent-staff/bill-clinton">Bill Clinton</option>
<option value="/listing-agent-staff/will-smith">Will Smith</option>
</select>
```

**please note the first part is generated automatically so the number of record varies, the number of options in the second part should cope with that.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$(".StaffBlock.StaffName a").each(function() {
    $(".cat_dropdown").append($("<option/>", {
        value: $(this).attr("href"),
        text: $(this).text()
    }));
});​
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nn6rp/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a -Container around the ...-Containers? If yes, you can easily iterate through them like var

`$('#id_of_main_container").children().each(function (e) {
    $(this).find('a').attr('href');
 }`

Using html(), you can easily build a array of -Tags with the href-Values and build a custom -tree.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var select = $('<select name="CAT_Custom_231994" id="CAT_Custom_231994" class="cat_dropdown"><option value="">-- Please select --</option></select>');
    $('div.StaffBlock.StaffName a').each(function() {
        select.append('<option value="'+ $(this).attr('href') +'">'+ $(this).text() +'</option>');
    });
    $('div.StaffBlock.StaffName').last().after(select).after('<label for="CAT_Custom_231994">Listing Contact :</label>');
});​
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tAxTH/2/)